# How do I fix tables for Mobile-View?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table

I do not know how to fix a table I have made for a website for mobile phone view

Here's the website:
http://acharneskungfu.com/schedule/

The only thing I want to fix is the mobile/responsive view.
The schedule/program is exactly as my client needs it.

Any ideas please?

Here's the code:

```html
 <meta charset="UTF-8"> 

<table border="3" align="center">

 <thead> 
   <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΩΡΕΣ</th>
   <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΔΕΥΤΕΡΑ</th>
   <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΤΡΙΤΗ</th>
   <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΤΕΤΑΡΤΗ</th>
   <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΕΜΠΤΗ</th>
   <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΑΡΑΣΚΕΥΗ</th>
 </thead>

  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: black;">09:00-10:30</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #cc00cc; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΡΩΙΝΟ ΕΝΗΛΙΚΩΝ</td>
   <td></td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #cc00cc; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΡΩΙΝΟ ΕΝΗΛΙΚΩΝ</td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: black;">17:30-18:30</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #0066ff; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 1</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00ff66; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 2</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #0066ff; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 1</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00ff66; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 2</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff6600; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: black;">18:30-19:30</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff99cc; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 3</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff6600; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 4</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff99cc; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 3</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff6600; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 4</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff99cc; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: black;">19:30-20:30</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00cc33; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 1</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ffff00; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 2</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00cc33; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 1</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ffff00; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 2</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00cc33; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: black;">20:30-21:30</td>
   <td></td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00ffff; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΤΑΙ ΤΣΙ</td>
   <td></td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00ffff; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΤΑΙ ΤΣΙ</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ffff00; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px;">20:30-22:00</td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff3333; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 3</td>
   <td></td>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff3333; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 3</td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>

</table>


<table border="3" align="center">

 <thead> 
   <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΤΜΗΜΑ</th>
   <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΕΡΙΓΡΑΦΗ</th>
 </thead>


  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #cc00cc; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΡΩΙΝΟ ΕΝΗΛΙΚΩΝ</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">2 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #0066ff; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 1</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">Παιδιά αρχάρια από 4 έως 6,5 ετών, 2 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00ff66; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 2</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">Παιδιά αρχάρια από 4 έως 6,5 ετών, 2 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff99cc; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 3</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">Παιδιά αρχάρια από 7 έως 11 ετών, 3 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff6600; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 4</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">Παιδιά αρχάρια από 7 έως 11 ετών, 3 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00cc33; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 1</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">Προχωρημένοι και Έφηβοι έως 18 ετών, 3 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ffff00; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 2</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">Προχωρημένοι και Έφηβοι έως 18 ετών, 3 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00ffff; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΤΑΙ ΤΣΙ</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">2 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff3333; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 3</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">2 φορές (1,5 ώρα) την εβδομάδα</td>
  </tr>

 </table>
```

This is some random text because I had to add more details where I believe I have met the requirements for expressing my problem.
Please do not mind.

Comment: First of all, you need to define what you mean by "fix". Define the current unwanted behavior and also describe what should happen. Second of all, do not use a link to a live website. Update the example in the question instead. Because the website will change and your question needs to remain relevant for anyone having a similar problem. If it doesn't, it won't help anyone else and that's one of the conditions for getting help on SO: your question needs to remain helpful and relevant for others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for this would be to allow the table to scroll horizontally on mobile:

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
  <table border="3" align="center">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
div.tab1,div.tab2{

  overflow-x: auto;

}
</style>

</head>

<body>



<div class="tab1">
<table border="3" align="center">

    <thead>
      <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΩΡΕΣ</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΔΕΥΤΕΡΑ</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΤΡΙΤΗ</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΤΕΤΑΡΤΗ</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΕΜΠΤΗ</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΑΡΑΣΚΕΥΗ</th>
    </thead>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: black;">09:00-10:30</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #cc00cc; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΡΩΙΝΟ ΕΝΗΛΙΚΩΝ</td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #cc00cc; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΡΩΙΝΟ ΕΝΗΛΙΚΩΝ</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: black;">17:30-18:30</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #0066ff; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 1</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00ff66; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 2</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #0066ff; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 1</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00ff66; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 2</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff6600; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 4</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: black;">18:30-19:30</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff99cc; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 3</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff6600; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 4</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff99cc; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 3</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff6600; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 4</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff99cc; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: black;">19:30-20:30</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00cc33; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 1</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ffff00; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 2</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00cc33; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 1</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ffff00; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 2</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00cc33; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 1</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: black;">20:30-21:30</td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00ffff; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΤΑΙ ΤΣΙ</td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00ffff; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΤΑΙ ΤΣΙ</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ffff00; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px;">20:30-22:00</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff3333; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 3</td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff3333; font-size: 14px; color: black;">ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 3</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

</table>
</div>
<div class="tab2">
<table border="3" align="center">

    <thead>
      <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΤΜΗΜΑ</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΕΡΙΓΡΑΦΗ</th>
    </thead>


        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #cc00cc; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΡΩΙΝΟ ΕΝΗΛΙΚΩΝ</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">2 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #0066ff; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 1</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">Παιδιά αρχάρια από 4 έως 6,5 ετών, 2 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00ff66; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 2</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">Παιδιά αρχάρια από 4 έως 6,5 ετών, 2 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff99cc; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 3</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">Παιδιά αρχάρια από 7 έως 11 ετών, 3 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff6600; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΑΙΔΙΚΟ 4</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">Παιδιά αρχάρια από 7 έως 11 ετών, 3 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00cc33; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 1</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">Προχωρημένοι και Έφηβοι έως 18 ετών, 3 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ffff00; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΕΦΗΒΟΙ / ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 2</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">Προχωρημένοι και Έφηβοι έως 18 ετών, 3 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #00ffff; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΤΑΙ ΤΣΙ</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">2 φορές την εβδομάδα</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #ff3333; font-size: 16px; color: black;">ΠΡΟΧΩΡΗΜΕΝΟΙ 3</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; color: black;">2 φορές (1,5 ώρα) την εβδομάδα</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```